# How do I compare ClassNames so that I can remove a TD tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to compare the class names of a `<TD>` and `<TR>` element. If they match, I need to be able to remove the `TD` when I click the `TR`. Here is some code :

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("table").find("tr:not(:nth-child(1))").remove();
});

$("tr").click(function() {
  $(this).append($("<td>", {
    text: $(this).attr("class")
  }));
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#table td {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#table th {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 25px
}

div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr class="class1">
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class2">
        <td>2014</td>
        <td>$10000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class3">
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>$8000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class4">
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>$9000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
      <input id="button1" type="button" value="Click to remove all rows except first one" />
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Now I have it working so that I can add the `TD` when I click the `TR`, but the issue is that it keeps adding the `TD`. I need to remove it once it has been added by clicking the `TR` again. In order to do that I need to compare the class names of the newly created `TD` and the existing `TR`. If they match I need to remove it.

Comment: The TD doesn't have a class, you put the TR's class in the text. Is that what you want to compare?

Comment: The goal is to add/remove a <td>, so why don't you use the hide/show approach instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.filter()` to look for a `td` whose text matches the class of the `tr` you click on. If you find any, remove them, otherwise add a new one.

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("table").find("tr:not(:nth-child(1))").remove();
});

$("tr").click(function() {
  var classname = $(this).attr("class");
  var tr = $(this).find("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == classname;
  });
  if (tr.length == 0) {
    $(this).append($("<td>", {
      text: classname
    }));
  } else {
    tr.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#table td {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#table th {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 25px
}

div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr class="class1">
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class2">
        <td>2014</td>
        <td>$10000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class3">
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>$8000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class4">
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>$9000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
      <input id="button1" type="button" value="Click to remove all rows except first one" />
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about filter! I appreciate it, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you don't even need to compare classes. Which is handy as you never assign a class to the new cell.

Instead show and hide the cell based on cell count

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("table").find("tr:not(:nth-child(1))").remove();
});

$("tr").click(function() {
  //If we have 2 cell add
  if($(this).find("td").length === 2) {  
  $(this).append($("<td>", {
    text: $(this).attr("class")
  }));
  //Otherwise remove
  }else{
    $(this).find("td:last-child").remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#table td {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#table th {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 25px
}

div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr class="class1">
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class2">
        <td>2014</td>
        <td>$10000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class3">
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>$8000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class4">
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>$9000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
      <input id="button1" type="button" value="Click to remove all rows except first one" />
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround. I use hide/show the `<TD>` instead of class comparison.

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("table").find("tr:not(:nth-child(1))").remove();
});

  $(".class2").click(function() {
    $(".TD2").toggleClass("show");
  });
  $(".class3").click(function() {
    $(".TD3").toggleClass("show");
  });
  $(".class4").click(function() {
    $(".TD4").toggleClass("show");
  });
```

```css
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #table td {
      padding: 25px;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #table th {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding: 25px
    }
    div {
      display: block;
    }
.TD2, .TD3, .TD4 {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr class="class1">
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class2">
        <td>2014</td>
        <td>$10000</td>
        <td class="TD2">class2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class3">
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>$8000</td>
        <td class="TD3">class3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="class4">
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>$9000</td>
        <td class="TD4">class4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
      <input id="button1" type="button" value="Click to remove all rows except first one" />
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```